# Is it possible to attach more than 1 file in IE8?

Tags: java, file-upload, internet-explorer-8, activex

I know that it has been asked a lot of times, but I have not found a solution yet. I faced a client who wants a multiple file uploader working in IE8 and I can not achieve this the last 2 days.

The whole website is written in JAVA and that is what makes it harder for me. I already found tons of methods for php or .NET, but nothing really helpfull for my case.

Basically I was thinking of an `ActiveX` control, but it sounds kinda crazy to implement it in my JAVA code.
Do you have any ideas on how to bypass this issue? I guess that there is something I'm missing here. If there is not an easy/average way to do this I will be pushed to write an applet, but I'm trying to avoid it, as it have security issues and most of the users don't like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue using [uplodify](http://www.uploadify.com/) It was an easy solution. I hope that it will help you, if you have file uploading troubles like me.